# facebook messenger get started button don't send messaging_postbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-messenger

Playing around with a dummy facebook app nd ruby on rails to set-up a messenger bot. My goal is to trigger a sign up when the user first interacts with the bot by clicking the default 'Get Started" button. I have added a get started button this way:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload":"GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=TOKEN
```

Then received:

```
{"result":"success"}
```

By looking at my server logs, I notice I dont get any callback from the user action. I know the webhook is set correctly cause other bot features seems to work right. So here is my question: I use pages_messaging permission on facebook apps, I think the reason why might be I need pages_messaging_subscriptions in order to get back that data. Can this difference explains why I don't get back any data on user clicking Get started?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Subscription permission is not needed to receive the post back. Two things to check: 1. Do a GET on /messenger_profile to check that the get started was set as expected. 2. Double check your webhook settings to make sure you are subscribed to receive messaging_postbacks events.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but it seems like they don't offer something such as a messenging_postbacks anymore on the actual facebook app panel. Now there are 6 categories and subcategories such as:

`Categories: 
User
Page
Permissions
Application
Native Components
Instagram`

And I can't see any messaging postback togglable feature in any of these.

How can I make that get to /messenger_profile btw, do you have a curl example?

Comment: I ran:

curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?fields=get_started&access_token=TOKEN"

and received: 

{"data":[{"get_started":{"payload":"GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"}}]

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong place in the app settings. You need to add Messenger under products. Then in the messenger settings you will see a webhook setup where you can select messaging_postbacks